# window.onbeforeunload not showing messages in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm showing an alert message on certain conditions when an user tries to leave. The message is shown in Safari, but it doesn't work in Chrome.
I tried two things like following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    if ($scope.isFormChanged == true) {
        event.returnValue = 'Don\'t go yet! Save your changed data before you leave!';
    }
}

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if ($scope.isFormChanged == true) {
            return 'Don\'t go yet! Save your changed data before you leave!'
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works fine for me.. Are you sure that `$scope.isFormChanged` is `true`?

Comment: @choz, Yeah I checked everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works in chrome. And I have also doubt with isFormChanged. 
`<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
        return "Are you sure you want to close window?"
    }
 </script>`